# Java: Cannot change a JFrame component's content in another java file

Tags: java, jframe

i have this problem :

- i have a JFrame GUI class GUIView.java :

  ```
       public class GUIView extends JFrame{ 

          //other instance variables
          ....
          public JTextArea gameGuide; 

          //constructor
          public GUIView(){ 
              ...
              initGUI();

          } 
          //init GUI
          public void initGUI(){
              //add other components
              ... 
              gameGuide = new JTextArea(); 

              //set layout 
              ...
              add(gameGuide);
          }
         public void setText(String s){
              this.gameGuide.setText(s);
         }

         public void showGame(){
              GUIView f = new GUIView() ; 
              f.setSize(450,600); 
              f.setTitle("TIC TAC TOE ONLINE");
              f.setResizable(false);
              f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
              f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
              f.setVisible(true); 
          }
     }
  ```

  -Then i have a file called Worker.java

  ```
  public class Worker { 
      public GUIView guiView; 

      public Worker(GUIView guiView) {
          this.guiView= guiView; 
      }

      public static void main(String[] args){
          GUIView guiView = new GUIView();
          Worker worker = new Worker(guiView);
          guiView.setText("testing if this will work");
          guiView.showGame();
      } }
  ```

the GUI works, it shows a blank gameGuide text area.

in Worker.java, i tried changing the content of gameGuide but the String in gameGUI.setText() did not show up.

i tried set visible true -> false -> true, still did not work.

Please explain why ? and is there a way i can change the content of the component gameGuide textArea in Worker.java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help. Actually, two different GUIView JFrames were created.

```
public void showGame(){
            setSize(450,600);
            setTitle("TIC TAC TOE ONLINE");
            setResizable(false);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you ! you, Raju and Mr. Andre have resolved my Problems very thoroughly !!

Answer (score 1):

You create a new `GUIView` in your `showGame()` method everytime. You will always see that one, no matter what you set on the other one before.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    GUIView guiView = new GUIView(); // creates a GUIView
    Worker worker = new Worker(guiView);
    guiView.setText("testing if this will work"); // changes the created GUIView
    guiView.showGame(); // creates an entirely new GUIView and shows that one instead
}
```

Comment: Thank you !! I see the problem now !! you, Mr Andre and Raju have helped me immensely !